# Problem with Deleting local branch using git Terminal

Tags: git

I tried deleting the local branch using Git Terminal but ended up with errors. Please have a look at the code snippet attached below for more Info.

```
git branch -D feature/sysCAN
error: invalid color value: yellow
fatal: bad config variable 'color.branch.upstream' in file 'C:/Users/Himavanth/.
gitconfig' at line 7
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Remove line 7 from your gitconfig and try again

Comment: @Christian I'm really surprised by how the time to create a Stackoverflow account and writing a question could have been spent just reading the error message...

Comment: include a copy of `C:/Users/Himavanth/.gitconfig` in your post, please

Answer (score -3):

use the `git checkout` command to move off the branch you wish to delete.

```
git branch --delete <branchname>
```

Run the `git branch -a` command to verify the local Git branch is deleted.

**Note:** You cannot delete a branch that is currently checked out.